# PHP mail() function with gmail as receiver (noname.txt as attachment instead of text message)

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have a problem with sending emails to gmail through Php mail() function. I tested this script with my yahoo mail and there is no problem (email body has no attachments). Here is my code:

```
$mailto = "info@email.com";
$charset = "utf-8";
$subject = "subject text";
$content = "text/html";

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: $content  charset=$charset\n";
    $headers .= "Date: ".date("Y-m-d (H:i:s)",time())."\n";
    $headers .= "From: \"".$mailto."\" <".$mailto.">\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: My Send E-mail\n";
    $message = "message text";

    mail($_POST['posEmail'],$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Note that this code could be **very** dangerous unless used in a protected environment only. One should sanitize all parameters to mail() or one will get in trouble (there are robots out there that automatically check if your script is vulnerable, so this script would be abused for spamming sooner or later). The vulnerability is in first parameter which is taken from $_POST directly. Of course, you might be protecting access to this script with other means. YMMV.

Comment: @Pilgrim You have told that problem with sending email to GMAIL, Have you checked in spam folder ? and please mention your **error**...

Comment: @johndodo thanks for caution. i will add defence to Post variables.    I receive email, but text message receives as attachment not as regular text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [phpmailer](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/264-PHP-Full-featured-email-transfer-class-for-PHP.html) class, it is much safer and easier to use. And it supports attachments and similar.

Comment: I need a simple register script, and think, that phpmailer too big for that porpose

Answer (score 1):

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: $content; charset=$charset\n";
```

The semicolon between content and charset?

And try terminating the line with \r\n, not \n.

Comment: i review headers from original mail and there was an ; between content type and charset. I was trying both \r\n and \n nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$headers =  'To: ' . $epost . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $mailto . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Message-ID: <' . $ordernummer . ">\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable';
```

These headers work. I was also getting mails as an attachment named `noname.txt`.

I Added `Message-ID`, `Content-Transfer-Encoding`, took away Real Names from `To` and `From`, skipped the `<>` around the emails, took away quotes around `text/plain` and around `UTF-8` which I capitalized.

Comment: thanks, after hours of trying this thing to work i use phpmailer.

Answer (score 0):

you just edit your php.ini and put this

> SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
>
> smtp_port = 25
>
> sendmail_from = youremailid@gmail.com
>
> [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the problem of the OP and, more, it won't work at all

Comment: i'm don't want to sen email from gmail account. i have a problem receiving mails to gmail account